# Laravel sending email call_user_func() error

Tags: mysql, laravel, email, laravel-5, laravel-5.6

I am trying to send email in laravel for which I am using the `mail::send` function.

This is my code:

```
$data = [
          'title'=>'Some Title',
          'content'=>'Content',
          'email'=> 'email',
          'password'=>'password',
          'remarks'=>'remarks'
      ];

      Mail::send('admin.mails.activate', $data, ['user'=>$user], function ($message) use ($user) {
          $message->to($user->email, $user->name)->subject('Account Activation Email')->from('support@webmail.com');
      });
```

I am trying to pass the $data variable to the view file and $user variable to the callback function so that I could use user's email to send an email. But it is giving me this error:

```
    call_user_func() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, array must have exactly two members
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Mail::send()` accepts 3 arguments (view, data, callback) but you've given it 4:

```
Mail::send('admin.mails.activate', $data, ['user'=>$user], function ($message) use ($user) {
    $message->to($user->email, $user->name)->subject('Account Activation Email')->from('support@webmail.com');
});
```

I assume you meant to merge the `['user' => $user]` array in with `$data`:

```
Mail::send('admin.mails.activate', array_merge($data, ['user' => $user]), function ($message) use ($user) {
    $message->to($user->email, $user->name)->subject('Account Activation Email')->from('support@webmail.com');
});
```

or alternatively:

```
$data = [
    'title'=>'Some Title',
    'content'=>'Content',
    'email'=> 'email',
    'password'=>'password',
    'remarks'=>'remarks',
    'user' => $user
];

Mail::send('admin.mails.activate', $data, function ($message) use ($user) {
    $message->to($user->email, $user->name)->subject('Account Activation Email')->from('support@webmail.com');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

this is the problem

```
$message->to($user->email, $user->name)
```

change it to

```
$message->to($user->email)
```